# How to change EditText content with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-edittext

We have a button in **HTML**. When the user clicks it, the value of my specific `EditText` should change, but it doesn't.

**Code:**

```
class ActivityTest extends Activity {

    TextView textView1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/htmlimages.html");
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyTest(), "Scripts");
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    }


    public class MyTest {

        void setText(String string) 
        {
            textView1.setText(string);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, what's the issue?

Comment: edit text content will not change...

Comment: hard code value in textView1.setText("hossein"); and test it

Comment: Where do you call your `setText` in the click listener of the button ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't change some native view with javaScript (any web based language), there is no api for JS.

You can't access to the views and less change his properties.

You can do everything on a webView if you are confident with web more than java.
Load your web and show there the label, then you can change everything with JS.

**Edit**: You can inject or call methods from JS with this API as Bob says.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not 100% correct...see WebView.addJavascriptInterface: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: @Bob9630 you are right, I edited my answer, thx to correct me, I didn't knew it when i answered this question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your html part is correct one thing that you need to do is make ui calls on the main thread.

so your code:

```
void setText(String string) 
{
   textView1.setText(string);
}
```

should be

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void setText() {
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {            
     @Override
     public void run() {
        textView.setText("Testing text");       
     }
  });       
}
```